# Should I remove my answer when question changes a bit

Tags: discussion

I came across a bad but not hopeless question today. So I asked the OP some questions to improve the quality and help clarify what he was asking for. He responded and also clearly wanted to improve his question. But when I asked what the underlying problem was he said he got an error, so my next step was asking him what kind of an error, but I also saw an infinity loop in his code, so I already made an answer pointing out this error, but apparently he got another problem. Should I now remove my answer, or leave it as is?

The question for clarification:
[how to read from the xml node using c# as per my requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741334/how-to-read-from-the-xml-node-using-c-sharp-as-per-my-requirement/34746218#34746218)

Comment: Ah [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)... in general the OP really shouldn't pull the rug out from under you with an edit, so you should not remove your answer.  However, with a vague title like "how to ... per my requirement" I think you are answering a poorly defined question.

Comment: @ryanyuyu This isn't a chameleon question, the question was unanswerable, and the OP posted an answer anyway.  A chameleon question is a good (or at least answerable) question that changes once answered.

Comment: It's indeed not a chameleon question, and I answered to soon, that's why I was having doubts if I should remove it now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You posted an answer when you very clearly didn't have enough information to diagnose the problem.  You should have voted to close the question, not answered it when there wasn't enough information to post an answer.

Your answer is (by your own admission) not solving the problem that the question is asking to be solved, so yes, you should absolutely delete it.  This is why we vote to close questions without enough information, rather than trying to answer them.